# Adobe InDesign Javascript: Parse XML String & Place Into Textbox

Tags: javascript, xml, adobe, adobe-indesign

I'm using the XML class to parse an XML string. I want to insert the parsed XML into a textbox. What is the proper way to accomplish this?

My Code:

```
var myXML = new XML( '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><myText>Hello World</myText></root>' );
app.selection[0].placeXML( myXML );
// app.selection[0].placeXML( myXML.elements()[0] );
```

This Generates Error 30477:

```
Invalid value for parameter 'using' of method 'placeXML'. Expected XMLElement, but received nothing.
```

Comment: What about ``var myXML = jQuery.parseXML( ' ...`` ?

Comment: @JonasM.Schlatter jquery doesn't even work in indesign? I was also hoping that InDesign would insert the text into the textbox with the tags applied.

Comment: The native JavaScript's XML element is something different than InDesign's version `XMLElement` – they are not freely interchangeable. Either write code to convert it, or (easier and quite possibly faster) save your XML to a file and use InDesign's native methods to load it again.